# Given a user's SID, how can I get the AD DirectoryEntry?

Tags: c#, sid, directoryentry

I have the user's SID as `byte[]` within `windowsPrincipal.getIdentity().getSid()`.
How can I get an Active Directory entry (DirectoryEntry) from the SID?

Answer (score 11):

Use the [SecurityIdentifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.securityidentifier%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class to convert the sid from byte[] format to string and then bind directly to the object:

```
DirectoryEntry OpenEntry(byte[] sidAsBytes)
{
    var sid = new SecurityIdentifier(sidAsBytes, 0);

    return new DirectoryEntry(string.Format("LDAP://<SID={0}>", sid.ToString()));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I found this example in c#

```
    // SID must be in Security Descriptor Description Language (SDDL) format
    // The PrincipalSearcher can help you here too (result.Sid.ToString())
    public void FindByIdentitySid()
    {
        UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(
            adPrincipalContext,
            IdentityType.Sid,
            "S-1-5-21-2422933499-3002364838-2613214872-12917");
        Console.WriteLine(user.DistinguishedName);
    }
```

Converted to VB.NET:

```
    ' SID must be in Security Descriptor Description Language (SDDL) format
    ' The PrincipalSearcher can help you here too (result.Sid.ToString())
    Public Sub FindByIdentitySid()
        Dim user As UserPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(adPrincipalContext,     IdentityType.Sid, "S-1-5-21-2422933499-3002364838-2613214872-12917")
        Console.WriteLine(user.DistinguishedName)
    End Sub
```

Obviously you can then:

```
    dim de as new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" & user.DistinguishedName)
```

To get the SID = S-1-5-21-***** (sorry VB.NET)

```
    ' Convert ObjectSID to a String

    ' http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/57452aab-4b68-4444-aefa-136b387dd06e

    Dim ADpropSid As Byte()
    ADpropSid = de.Properties("objectSid").Item(0)    
    ' in my test the byte field looks like this : 01 02 00 00 00 00.......37 02 00 00
    Dim SID As New System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier(ADpropSid, 0)
```

I haven't tested the C# or used the converted version yet myself, but have used the above to return the SID in SDDL format.

Comment: wow you and i have different definitions of "obvious". Why can you do a query on `"LDAP://" & user.DistinguishedName` like that? Don't you need to specify hostname etc? Does that require you are on the same machine that has active directory access?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way I've found is using LDAP binding.  Similar to what Nick Giles said.  More info at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675562%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
''' <summary>
''' Gets the DirectoryEntry identified by this SecurityIdentifier.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="id">The SecurityIdentifier (SID).</param>
<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()> _
Public Function GetDirectoryEntry(ByVal id As SecurityIdentifier) As DirectoryEntry
    Const sidBindingFormat As String = "LDAP://AOT/<SID={0}>"

    Return New DirectoryEntry(String.Format(sidBindingFormat, id.Value))
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

This can also be done in PowerShell, as long as you have .Net 3.5 or 4.0 available (see https://gist.github.com/882528 if you don't by default)

```
add-type -assemblyname system.directoryservices.accountmanagement
$adPrincipalContext = 
    New-Object System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext( 
    [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ContextType]::Domain)
$user = [system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.userprincipal]::findbyidentity(
    $adPrincipalContext
    , [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.IdentityType]::Sid
    , "S-1-5-21-2422933499-3002364838-2613214872-12917")
$user.DisplayName
$user.DistinguishedName
```